# Trying to generate list of non-zero integers in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, instantiation-error

I'm trying to define the function `int(?X)` in prolog which is a non-zero integer number generator which works like this:

```
?- int(X). X = 1 ; X = -1 ; X = 2 ; X = -2 ;
```

I tried the following with no luck:

```
int(X):- positives(Y), Y is abs(X).

positives(1).
positives(X):- positives(Y), X is Y+1.
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How can I make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Please retain the tags that are relevant for solving your issue. The tags are meant to help **other readers** find answers that are related to the topics they are looking for, not to reflect non-sensical requirements of instructors! I have restored the [tag:clpfd] tag, because using CLP(FD) constraints gets rid of the [tag:instantiation-error] that is the core issue of your question and many others on stackoverflow. This is because instructors currently still teach Prolog as it was 30 years ago, and over time these issues will be resolved by pointing them to declarative solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way to find and correct such problems.

1. Step one: Put **[clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)** constraints in your program. To do this, simply<sup>1</sup> replace `(is)/2` by the CLP(FD) constraint `(#=)/2`, i.e.:

   ```
   int(X) :- positives(Y), Y #= abs(X).

   positives(1).
   positives(X):- positives(Y), X #= Y+1.
   ```
2. Step two: The query now completes *without* errors, and shows you what you are describing:

   ```
   ?- int(X).
   X in -1\/1 ;
   X in -2\/2 ;
   X in -3\/3 ;
   X in -4\/4 .
   ```

   So, from the above, you see that what you are describing is *not sufficient* to obtain ground solutions: There is still a certain degree of freedom in your relations.
3. Step three: To actually fix the problem, we think about what we actually want to describe. Here is a start:

   ```
   int(X) :- positives(Y), ( X #= Y ; X #= -Y).
   ```
4. Step four: We try it out:

   ```
   ?- int(X).
   X = 1 ;
   X = -1 ;
   X = 2 ;
   X = -2 ;
   X = 3 ;
   etc.
   ```

Seems to work **OK**, except for the fact that *natural numbers* are actually never negative. I leave fixing this discrepancy between the title of your question and the relation you are describing as an exercise for you.

TL;DR: When reasoning over integers, use your system's **CLP(FD) constraints**, then take it from there.

---

<sub>I am assuming that you have already put `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` somewhere in your initial file, so that you can use CLP(FD) constraints in all your programs.</sub>

Comment: It's a good solution but I need one without using clpfd or any other library. It's not necessary to use my code and try to fix it. I can accept a solution totally different from what I have written.

Comment: To satisfy the urge for a 1970-style solution, you can simply perform Step 1 in reverse: Replace `(#=)/2` by `(is)/2` in the solution we found, and *voilà*, the nonsensical requirement is fulfilled!